When to use <Link to="" /> from react-router-dom and anchor tag? (React Router Dom Version 6.24.1)
I have a React 18 application and I am using the react-router-dom version 6.24.1. I am getting confused as to when I should use the <Link /> tag and when I should use the <a> (anchor) tag in a React app?
Is the <Link /> tag to be used for navigation within the application only? And is the anchor tag used for external links outside the app? Please see the below code:
Menu.jsx file:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = () => {
  const padding = {
    paddingRight: 5
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" style={padding}>anecdotes</Link>
      <Link to="/create" style={padding}>create new</Link>
      <Link to="/about" style={padding}>about</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

Footer.jsx file:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Footer = () => (
  <div>
    Google search for <Link to='https://www.google.com/' target="_blank">Google</Link>.

    or

    Google search for <a href='https://www.google.com/' target="_blank">Google</a>.
  </div>
);

How do I decide when to use the Link tag and the anchor tag? What is the best practice?

<Link> change the URL without causing full page reload.  This allows for smoother transitions and maintains the state of the application.
<a href="..."> Standard HTML element for navigation, It causes a full page reload, even if the destination is within the same application. This can be useful for external links or when you need to ensure a full reload of the page.
